# WPF Expander that works like a Popup

Tags: wpf, expander, flyout

I'm looking for an expander control where the expanding part is more like a popup. Similar to a ComboBox's dropdown functionality.

Is there anything built into WPF that works like that? If not, Best recommendations?

Thanks!

Comment: try https://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2008/02/05/wpf-sample-series-expander-control-with-popup-content/

Comment: Great idea, and it works in some situations. However, it appears the zindex goes out the window in a listbox.  I am using this in a user control that I then use in the ItemTemplate of a listbox. In a listbox the Expander control is not drawn on top of the item below it.

Comment: Archive of the same article posted by Ayyappan: https://web-beta.archive.org/web/20140227121528/https://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2008/02/05/wpf-sample-series-expander-control-with-popup-content